# Android: What is the correct way to rotate a bitmap?

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, rotation

The problem is when the bitmap gets rotated "R0" degrees, it looks like if it changed the pivot point. What I want is for it to rotate around the middle of the bitmap, but I don't know how.

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.base);
       Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
       matrix.reset();
       matrix.setScale(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
       matrix.setTranslate(-bitmap.getHeight()/2, -bitmap.getHeight()/2);
       matrix.postRotate(R0);
       Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
       canvas.drawBitmap(b, x-24, y-40, null);
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: I'd remove: `matrix.setTranslate(-bitmap.getHeight()/2, -bitmap.getHeight()/2);` and **-24** and **-40** from `canvas.drawBitmap(b, x-24, y-40, null);`

Answer (score 0):

Try using matrix.`postTranslate`, instead of `setTranslate`, the latter will reset your matrix and `setScale` call will make no effect.